# Custom print style with Vue.JS print plugin

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to print a VueJS component with custom print style.

Three Vue plugins look interesting on this subject:
1.printd
2.vue-print-nb
3.html-to-paper

Out of the three only html-to-paper has a options object that can pass a custom css style in order to dynamically pass some print css.

My issue is that i can't seem to load the custom css, and also bootstrap classes are messed up on print action.

This is basically what i am doing.

```
import VueHtmlToPaper from 'vue-html-to-paper'

const options = {
  name: '_blank',
  specs: [
   'fullscreen=yes',
   'titlebar=yes',
   'scrollbars=no'
  ],
  styles: [
    'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    './myPrint.css'
  ]
}

Vue.use(VueHtmlToPaper, options)
```

Any suggestion is welcomed.
Thanks

Comment: @caniakyouaquestion: did you find a way to solve this question

Answer (score 3):

I have tried all these three I think the best one is [print.js](https://printjs.crabbly.com/) which is not specifically for Vue.js but it is easily install-able and usable in the vue components.

For example

```
<script>
import print from "print-js";
export default {
  methods: {
    printing() {
      const style =
        "@page { margin-top: 400px } @media print { h1 { color: blue } }";
      const headerStyle = "font-weight: 300;";
      printJS({
        printable: "rrr",
        type: "html",
        header: "Doctor Name",
        headerStyle: headerStyle,
        style: style,
        scanStyles: false,
        onPrintDialogClose: () => console.log("The print dialog was closed"),
        onError: e => console.log(e)
      });
    },
    printVisit(id) {
      this.$htmlToPaper("rrr");
      this.$htmlToPaper("rrr", () => {
        console.log("Printing completed or was cancelled!");
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: According to your code here, the print() method uses printJS  (not print), so it must be imported by that name.

Answer (score 1):

VueHtmlToPaper opens a new window with its own style tag. So when you pass a CDN it works, if u pass a local file it does not because it tries to access the resource in your web server but in the wrong URL. Let's see how the page looks when we use a CDN and a local CSS file.

#### CDN

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="style" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Local CSS file

And let's say you are calling the print function from `http://localhost:8080/somepage`

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="style" href="./myPrint.css">
    </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will try to open `http://localhost:8080/somepage/myPrint.css`. Obviously this will not be accessible to print dialogue.

#### Solution

1. Put your custom CSS file in the public or static folder (Where you usually keep favicon)
2. Modify script path in options, prepend server basepath with the CSS file

#### Sample Option

```js
import VueHtmlToPaper from 'vue-html-to-paper'

/* This will change according to your server */
let basePath= 'http://localhost:8080';

const options = {
  name: '_blank',
  specs: [
   'fullscreen=yes',
   'titlebar=yes',
   'scrollbars=no'
  ],
  styles: [
    'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    `${basePath}/myPrint.css`
  ]
}

Vue.use(VueHtmlToPaper, options)
```

Also, the simplest way to access root-relative path is to use `/`. User `/style.css` instead of `./style.css`